# Files upload testing in Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, sinon, chai, enzyme

I have a FileInput in my render function

```
      <FileInput
      accept= "image/jpeg,image/png,audio/mp3"
      onChange= {this.fileInputOnChange}
      children= {<i className="fa fa-paperclip"/>}
      className= 'fileInput'
      />
```

I need to write a test for file upload, when I simulate the  change function it call the function fileInputOnChange

```
fileInputOnChange: function(evt){
var file = evt.target.files[0];
var fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onload = function(readFile){
  // Check the file type.
  var fileType = file.type.toLowerCase();

  if(fileType.lastIndexOf('image') === 0 && (fileType.lastIndexOf('png') >= 0 || fileType.lastIndexOf('jpeg'))){
    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = function(){
      var attachedFile = {
        attached: file,
        mediaSource: readFile.target.result,
        type: 'image'
      } 
        this.props.onChange(attachedFile);
    }.bind(this);

    image.onerror = function(){
      this.props.onError("INVALID_TYPE");
    }.bind(this);

    image.src = readFile.target.result;
  }else if(fileType.lastIndexOf('audio') === 0 && fileType.lastIndexOf('mp3') >= 0){
    //@todo: manage audio upload here
    var audio = new Audio();

    audio.oncanplaythrough = function(){
      var attachedFile = {
        attached: file,
        mediaSource: readFile.target.result,
        type: 'audio'
      } 
        this.props.onChange(attachedFile);
    }.bind(this);

    audio.onerror = function(e){
      this.props.onError("INVALID_TYPE");
    }.bind(this)

    audio.src = readFile.target.result;

  }else if (fileType.lastIndexOf('video') === 0 && fileType.lastIndexOf('mp4') >= 0){        
    var video = document.createElement('video');

    video.oncanplaythrough = function(){
      var attachedFile = {
        attached: file,
        mediaSource: readFile.target.result,
        type: 'video'
      } 
        this.props.onChange(attachedFile);
    }.bind(this);

    video.onerror = function(){
      this.props.onError("INVALID_TYPE");
    }.bind(this)

    video.src = readFile.target.result;
  }
}.bind(this);

fileReader.onerror = function(){
  this.props.onError("READING_ERROR");
}.bind(this)

fileReader.readAsDataURL(file); }
```

I could not add any files while simulating the upload button, I am confused of how to write the test for this scenario. Anyone ever came across this kinda scenarios? I would be greatful for all sorta helps.

```
it('testing attachfile change function...',()=>{
 const wrapper=shallow(<AttachFile />);
 wrapper.find('FileInput').simulate('change');
 console.log(wrapper.debug());
 });
```

When I tried the above test I got the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
  at [object Object].fileInputOnChange (js/components/home/chats/AttachFile.react.js:11:16)
  at node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:768:23
  at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.Mixin.perform (node_modules/react/lib/Transaction.js:138:20)
  at Object.ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates (node_modules/react/lib/ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:63:19)
  at batchedUpdates (node_modules/react/lib/ReactUpdates.js:98:20)
  at node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:767:45
  at withSetStateAllowed (node_modules/enzyme/build/Utils.js:196:3)
  at ShallowWrapper.simulate    (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:764:42)
  at Context.<anonymous> (test/sample.js:40:27)
```

Comment: got any solution to simulate change???

Answer (score 22):

You'll need to provide a mocked event object, something like:

```
wrapper.find('FileInput').simulate('change', {
  target: {
     files: [
       'dummyValue.something'
     ]   
  }
});
```

Your component its making a lot of work inside, its like a huge side effect (it defines two callbacks with logic nailed). It's going to be difficult, but I suppose you'll need to mock FileReader as well using two spies, one reacting to the `readAsDataURL` calling the `onload` and another one calling the `onerror`.

Then you can check if your callbacks are doing what is supposed to.

Hope it helps!